# What is the difference between the classes ArchiverTar and Archive_Tar?

Tags: 7

What is the difference between the classes [`ArchiverTar`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.archiver.inc/class/ArchiverTar/7) and [`Archive_Tar`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.tar.inc/class/Archive_Tar/7)?

I am mostly interested to understand which one a Drupal module is supposed to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Archive_Tar class is a very-slightly modified version of the [PEAR library Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/). ArchiverTar can be thought of as a wrapper to that library. However, depending on what your module is trying to achieve, you will probably want to call [archiver_get_archiver()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/archiver_get_archiver/7), since this is agnostic of the specific archive format (the system module supplies tar and zip, and your module could provide additional formats using [hook_archiver_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_archiver_info/7)).